# OpenAPI generate interface for Spring code that accepts the Authentication object?

Tags: spring, spring-security, openapi, openapi-generator

There are various ways to access the authentication information in a Spring REST application, as outlined here: https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

At the moment, I use [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate spring interfaces for my REST API and then I obtain a reference to the `Authentication` by writing code in the implementation like:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

As shown in the referenced article in Section 2.

I'd prefer to use the mechanism shown in Section 3 of the referenced article.
That is, I want the openapi-generator to add an `Authentication` parameter to the interfaces it generates, like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
  return authentication.getName();
}
```

How do I tell the openapi-generator to add `Authentication` parameters to the interface methods that it generates?